# What is the practical way to use minikube?

Tags: minikube

I have a Windows 10 desktop PC, and use Ubuntu in Virtualbox as my development environment.

I want to try out minikube, so I installed minikube in Ubuntu. But the problem now is, after managing installing Virtualbox in Ubuntu (which is a little strange, isn't it?), it says I need to enable VT-x which is already being enabled.

My question is, what is the practical way to use minikube on Windows 10? It seems I need a real Linux environment (not in Virtualbox)?

Answer (score 2):

You can run it directly on windows using the minikube.exe.  This uses either the built in Hyper-V hypervisor or with virtualbox.

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.14.0

[0] https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.14.0/minikube-windows-amd64.exe